# Fechar janela ao clicar em JButton

Tags: java, swing, jframe

É possível ao clicar em um botão e a `JFrame` ser fechada como se tivesse clicado no X da janela? Se for possível, como eu o crio?

Pelo que eu já estudei é usando `ActionListener` porem não encontro o código para fechar a janela.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É possível sim, você define um listener para o botão e dentro dele, invoca o método [`dispose()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose--) da instância do `JFrame` que deseja fechar dentro deste listener:

```
botao.addActionListener(e -> seuFrame.dispose());
```

Comment: Só mais uma pergunta e possível chamar o frame que eu usei o frame.dispose(); dnv caso queira?

Comment: @BitsofBytes se for o unico frame da aplicação, não, pois a JVM vai encerrar a aplicação. Se tiver outros, precisa criar uma nova instancia.

Comment: a aplicação de mais de 1 frame como eu faço?

Comment: @BitsofBytes não entendi o que você está querendo dizer.

Comment: deixa queto já sei como eu vou fazer